# determining repeated values in numpy array and adding them in another column python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array like

```
w = (1,3,4,5,6,2,9,2,4,2,1,3,3,6)
```

That is filled with repeated numbers. I want to make it look like:

```
w = ([[1, 5], [2, 2], [3, 1],..)
```

Which means I have to sort the array first and then count the repetitions of each values and then place the count beside them. So, the resulting array would be like:

```
w = ([value, count])
```

An example would be:

```
w = ( [1,2], [3,3], [4,2], [5,1],[6,2], [2,3],[9,1],[2,3], [4,2],[2,3],[1,2], [3,3], [3,3], [6,2])
```

I have already tried with "unique" but it sorts the values whereas i want the array as it is just with the counts beside every value. This was my attempt:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1])
unique, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)

np.asarray((unique, counts)).T


array([[1, 5],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 6],
       [5, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the first column in your output to be the full sequence of values in `w` (including repetitions), and the second column to be the counts for each value (also repeated for repeated values in `w`)?

You can do this using `np.unique` by returning both the item counts and the set of 'inverse' indices that reconstruct the original array from the unique values (in the example below, `uvals[idx]` would give you back `w`). You can use the inverse indices to index into the count values according to wherever the corresponding unique items occur within `w`:

```
w = np.array([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 9, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 6])
uvals, idx, counts = np.unique(w, return_counts=True, return_inverse=True)
out = np.vstack((w, counts[idx])).T

print(out)
# [[1 2]
#  [3 3]
#  [4 2]
#  [5 1]
#  [6 2]
#  [2 3]
#  [9 1]
#  [2 3]
#  [4 2]
#  [2 3]
#  [1 2]
#  [3 3]
#  [3 3]
#  [6 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scipy.stats.itemfreq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.itemfreq.html):

```
>>> from scipy.stats import itemfreq

>>> w = (1,3,4,5,6,2,9,2,4,2,1,3,3,6)
>>> itemfreq(w)
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 2],
       [5, 1],
       [6, 2],
       [9, 1]])
```

If you want a tuple of lists:

```
>>> tuple(itemfreq(w).tolist())
([1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1], [6, 2], [9, 1])
```